# How to convert a .avif images to video with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, avif

convert a .avif images to video with ffmpeg

by read ffmpeg doc, i run such cmd in shell:

```bash
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i *.avif -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

but only get some error:

```bash
ffmpeg version N-109896-g156ca86569 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/HEAD-156ca86_1 --enable-shared --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-demuxer=dash --enable-opencl --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon --disable-htmlpages --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavcodec     60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavformat    60.  4.100 / 60.  4.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  4.100 /  9.  4.100
  libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Option framerate not found.
```

my ffmpeg can convert png image to avif , i wonder if there have some ways to convert avif image to mp4 video.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to convert a.avif image to video with ffmpeg, you can use the following command in a terminal or command prompt window:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i input.avif -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```